# Package is missing after serverless and webpack build

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, webpack, serverless

I'm using webpack 4.41.6 version on my project, and exceljs 3.8.1. The problem is that after deployment to aws or just packaging, the "lib/doc/" package is missing in node_modules/exceljs.

I forked the project and rename the package to "lib/data" and everything works. I can not find what is actually removing that package and why.

This is from serverless.yml under custom configs

```
  webpack:
    includeModules:
      forceExclude:
        - aws-sdk
        - aws-lambda
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - rm -rf node_modules/aws-sdk
        - rm -rf node_modules/types
        - npx node-prune
```

Comment: Hi Henry, glad to have you around. Your chances of getting an answer are much better when you provide more complete information. You want to include your package.json and you webpack config (if it's not in the package.json). Use three backticks to have code formatted as code for readability

Comment: After spending not too much time, I found that node-prune was removing mentioned package. But I do not understand why. I edited my question you can find a piece of configs there.